# Can not use cocoapods (installation issue)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

I have settled a virtual machine (Mac OS) on PC. For the purposes of app development I was trying to install cocoapods. Installed Ruby and all the rest steps were taken.

However, when it comes to the cocoapods installation this is the thing that appears. I find it kind of weird. Never found anyone with such an issue.

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I'll agree, although...

> all the rest steps were taken

*What steps*? It seems one of them was installing [this](https://github.com/hdm/ruby-gem-install); so apparently you should uninstall it:

```
gem uninstall install
```

If that doesn't work raise hell with [the person](https://github.com/hdm) that made the "ruby-gem-install" gem.

Comment: Did you try quitting Terminal.app and then relaunching, and what was the output after using the uninstall command? You might need to use `sudo`...

Comment: Yes, I have tried that before. And with the sudo too. Still the same. The output is the same as shown in the intersted screenshot.